# Android Plus Compose Button

Tags: android

How do I add the compose button to my app? It's the button in the lower right corner of the many Google Apps, like Inbox. 
[image: compose button]

Where do I find this button?

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
    />

    <whatever.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/body"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```